# PTIJ: 3 Little Pigs traveling during Succos

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Based on the סברא of תשבו כעין תדורו, that a person lives in a Succah the way they live in their home, and normally people don't build houses when they're traveling on vacation (they stay in hotels, Airbnb, etc.) it's not expected of them to build a Succah. Would that mean then that the [3 little pigs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Little_Pigs), who *ARE* accustomed to building their own houses of straw, wood, or bricks would be Chayiv to build a Succah if they're traveling? Or perhaps [Bob the Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_the_Builder) would need to build a Succah since he constructs houses?

Sources:

[Succah 26a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.26a?lang=bi); [Mishna Berurah Hilchos Succah סימן תרמ, ח](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.640.8?lang=bi)

[image: 3 Little Pigs]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a precise reading of the Three Little Pigs in [its original Aramaic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0692307214), it seems that the bricks were strong enough for the structure to be considered permanent.

> בבעו מרי הב לי האיליין ליבנייא ואעביד בייתי
>
> ”Please, Sir, give me those bricks that I may build my house”;
>
> ...
>
> ועביד חזירא זעורא בייתיה עמהין
>
> and the little Pig built his house with them.
>
> אתה דיבא ונקש על תרעה ואמר חזירה זעורה חזירה זעורה שרי לי מיעול ואתיב חזירה לא בשערה על דיקני כלום הא איפח ואיפח ואפיל בייתך
>
> Along came the wolf, and he knocked at the door, and said, “Little pig, little pig, come let me in.” And the pig answered, “Not by the hair of my chinny chin Chin!” “Then I’ll huff and I’ll puff, and I’ll blow your house in!”
>
> והא נפח ונפח
>
> So he huffed and he huffed,
>
> ברם לית חייל ליה מפלה בייתה
>
> but he did not have the strength to blow the house in!
>
> (Steve Caruso translation)

Thus, it seems that while the Three Pigs are traveling they will indeed be exempt for this mitzvah.